# Get data from JSON nested arrays and put it into excel

Tags: python, json, excel

I have this JSON file with a collection of job descriptions:

```
{
 "name": "Messenger_group",
 "id": 85648902334,
 "messages": [
  {
   "id": 20482,
   "type": "message",
   "date": "2020-12-04T16:34:40",
   "from": "IFTTT",
   "from_id": 4535011322,
   "text": [
    "Random job description.\n\n",
    {
     "type": "bold",
     "text": "Budget"
    },
    ": $500\n",
    {
     "type": "bold",
     "text": "Posted On"
    },
    ": December 04, 2020 13:28 UTC\n",
    {
     "type": "bold",
     "text": "Category"
    },
    ": UX/UI Design\n",
    {
     "type": "link",
     "text": "https://url.com/"
    }
   ]
  },
  {
   "id": 21144,
   "type": "message",
   "date": "2020-12-06T01:04:50",
   "from": "IFTTT",
   "from_id": 4535011322,
   "text": [
    "Random job description.\n\n",
    {
     "type": "bold",
     "text": "Hourly Range"
    },
    ": $13.00-$35.00\n",
    {
     "type": "bold",
     "text": "Posted On"
    },
    ": December 05, 2020 21:31 UTC\n",
    {
     "type": "bold",
     "text": "Country"
    },
    ": Serbia\n",
    {
     "type": "link",
     "text": "https://url.com"
    }
   ]
  }
 ]
}
```

I would like to parse through this and extract certain values from each message's "text" array.
And then put them into an excel file.

The challenging part for me is to somehow connect items from inside of these arrays.
For example, I need to get "Hourly Range" part, make it a column header in excel, then take the very next item, "$13.00-$35.00\n", and put it underneath in the same column and so on.
If that's not easy enough, some messages have different sets of values. Like some have "hourly rates" and others got "fixed budgets", so somehow I need to account for that as well.

In the end, I would like to have a table that looks something like this:

[image: Example Table]

I am mostly using Python, so my question is which method or library I can use to do something like this?

Comment: you need `json` to read it and some module to write in excel (you can even write it as CSV using standard module `csv`) - rest you can do with `for`-loop` without any other module.

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar problem during one of my internships. The JSON was nested and I wanted to convert it into a table but it was not direct. Moreover my JSON file was huge.

I used the `ijson` [library](https://pypi.org/project/ijson/). It allows you to parse the json file in an iterative manner and it returns you the prefix, event, value tuple.

For example, this was the output when I parsed my JSON:
[image: ijson output]

After understanding the json structure, you can co-relate the prefix and event values and devise an algorithm to write some particular values into a CSV row.

Not sure if this is the most optimal approach, but it definitely worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

You may need `json` to read data, `csv` or other module to write data but rest you can do without any extra module - need only `for`-loop and dict/list functions

---

At the end you have full working example.

---

I use `json` to convert JSON string to Python data

```
import json

data = json.loads(text)
```

and then I can use `for`-loop to process data and convert to list of rows and every row will be dictionary:

```
{
   'Id': ..., 
   'Date': ..., 
   'Budget': ..., 
   'Category': ..., 
   'Country': ..., 
   'Posted On': ..., 
   'Hourly Range': ...
}
```

I use `for` loop to work with every `messages` separatelly and create row with default values for elements which may not exists in list `text`

```
all_rows = []

for msg in data['messages']:
    row = {
        'Id': msg['id'],
        'Date': msg['date'],
        'Budget': None,       # default value if it not in msg
        'Category': None,     # default value if it not in msg
        'Country': None,      # default value if it not in msg
        'Posted On': None,    # default value if it not in msg
        'Hourly Range': None, # default value if it not in msg
    }
```

I use `iter()` to convert list `text` to iterator and then I can use it with `zip(it, it)` to create pairs like: first element `{"type": "bold", "text": "Budget"}` and second element `": $500\\n"`. And then I can create pair `"Budget"` and `$500` and kee in `row`

```
text = msg['text']

it = iter(text) # to create pairs with `zip` 
next(it)        # skip first element: "Random job description.\\n\\n"

for x, y in zip(it, it):  # work with pairs
    key = x['text']                      # ie. "Budget"
    value = y.strip().replace(': ', '')  # ie. "$500"
    row[key] = value

all_rows.append(row)  # keep this row on list
```

After that I have list with all rows:

```
[
 {'Id': 20482, 'Date': '2020-12-04T16:34:40', 'Budget': '$500', 'Category': 'UX/UI Design', 'Country': None, 'Posted On': 'December 04, 2020 13:28 UTC', 'Hourly Range': None}, 
 {'Id': 21144, 'Date': '2020-12-06T01:04:50', 'Budget': None, 'Category': None, 'Country': 'Serbia', 'Posted On': 'December 05, 2020 21:31 UTC', 'Hourly Range': '$13.00-$35.00'}
]
```

And now I can use `csv` to write it in file `CSV` which I can read in `Excel`, `LibreOffice` or any other similar program (or in Python module `pandas`)

```
import csv

headers = ['Id', 'Date', 'Budget', 'Category', 'Country', 'Posted On', 'Hourly Range']

with open('output.csv', 'w') as fh:
    csv_writer = csv.DictWriter(fh, headers)

    csv_writer.writeheader()
    csv_writer.writerows(all_rows)
```

---

Minimal working example

```
text = '''
{
 "name": "Messenger_group",
 "id": 85648902334,
 "messages": [
  {
   "id": 20482,
   "type": "message",
   "date": "2020-12-04T16:34:40",
   "from": "IFTTT",
   "from_id": 4535011322,
   "text": [
    "Random job description.\\n\\n",
    {
     "type": "bold",
     "text": "Budget"
    },
    ": $500\\n",
    {
     "type": "bold",
     "text": "Posted On"
    },
    ": December 04, 2020 13:28 UTC\\n",
    {
     "type": "bold",
     "text": "Category"
    },
    ": UX/UI Design\\n",
    {
     "type": "link",
     "text": "https://url.com/"
    }
   ]
  },
  {
   "id": 21144,
   "type": "message",
   "date": "2020-12-06T01:04:50",
   "from": "IFTTT",
   "from_id": 4535011322,
   "text": [
    "Random job description.\\n\\n",
    {
     "type": "bold",
     "text": "Hourly Range"
    },
    ": $13.00-$35.00\\n",
    {
     "type": "bold",
     "text": "Posted On"
    },
    ": December 05, 2020 21:31 UTC\\n",
    {
     "type": "bold",
     "text": "Country"
    },
    ": Serbia\\n",
    {
     "type": "link",
     "text": "https://url.com"
    }
   ]
  }
 ]
}
'''

# --- read ---

import json

data = json.loads(text)

# --- process ---

all_rows = []

headers = ['Id', 'Date', 'Budget', 'Category', 'Country', 'Posted On', 'Hourly Range']

for msg in data['messages']:
    row = {
        'Id': msg['id'],
        'Date': msg['date'],
        'Budget': None,       # default value if it not in msg
        'Category': None,     # default value if it not in msg
        'Country': None,      # default value if it not in msg
        'Posted On': None,    # default value if it not in msg
        'Hourly Range': None, # default value if it not in msg
    }

    text = msg['text']

    it = iter(text)  # to create pairs with `zip` 
    next(it)         # skip first element

    for x, y in zip(it, it):
        key = x['text']
        value = y.strip().replace(': ', '')
        row[key] = value

    all_rows.append(row)

    for key,value in row.items():
        print(key, ':', value)
    print('---')

# --- write ---

import csv

with open('output.csv', 'w') as fh:
    csv_writer = csv.DictWriter(fh, headers)

    csv_writer.writeheader()
    csv_writer.writerows(all_rows)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I came up with after updating a very helpful @furas comment.

```
text = '''
{
 "name": "Messenger_group",
 "id": 85648902334,
 "messages": [
  {
   "id": 20482,
   "type": "message",
   "date": "2020-12-04T16:34:40",
   "from": "IFTTT",
   "from_id": 4535011322,
   "text": [
    "Random job description.\\n\\n",
    {
     "type": "bold",
     "text": "Budget"
    },
    ": $500\\n",
    {
     "type": "bold",
     "text": "Posted On"
    },
    ": December 04, 2020 13:28 UTC\\n",
    {
     "type": "bold",
     "text": "Category"
    },
    ": UX/UI Design\\n",
    {
     "type": "link",
     "text": "https://url.com/"
    }
   ]
  },
  {
   "id": 21144,
   "type": "message",
   "date": "2020-12-06T01:04:50",
   "from": "IFTTT",
   "from_id": 4535011322,
   "text": [
    "Random job description.\\n\\n",
    {
     "type": "bold",
     "text": "Hourly Range"
    },
    ": $13.00-$35.00\\n",
    {
     "type": "bold",
     "text": "Posted On"
    },
    ": December 05, 2020 21:31 UTC\\n",
    {
     "type": "bold",
     "text": "Country"
    },
    ": Serbia\\n",
    {
     "type": "link",
     "text": "https://url.com"
    }
   ]
  }
 ]
}
'''

import json
data = json.loads(text)

all_rows = []

include_params = [
    'Id',
    'Date',
    'Budget',
    'Category',
    'Country',
    'Posted On',
    'Hourly Range',
    'link',
]

for msg in data['messages']:
    row = {}

    if 'Id' in include_params:
        row['Id'] = msg['id']
    if 'Date' in include_params:
        row['Date'] = msg['date']

    text = msg['text']
    it = iter(text)
    for i in it:
        if type(i) == dict:
            if i['text'] in include_params:
                key = i['text']
                value = next(it).strip().replace(': ', '')
                row[key] = value
            if 'https://url' in i['text'] and 'link' in include_params:
                key = i['type']
                value = i['text']
                row[key] = value

    all_rows.append(row)

    for key,value in row.items():
        print(key, ':', value)
    print('---')


import csv

headers = include_params

with open('output_test.csv', 'w') as fh:
    csv_writer = csv.DictWriter(fh, headers)

    csv_writer.writeheader()
    csv_writer.writerows(all_rows)
```